# Repeatedly reading and returning chunks of data from enumeration

Tags: java, algorithm, enums

I have a Java function that looks like:

```
public List<File> myFunction(){
     Enumeration<File> myFiles = enumFiles();
     int i = 0;
      while(myFiles.hasMoreElements() && i < 50){
          // i will add the element to an arraylist here
           i++;
      }

     return "100 files from myFiles"
}
```

where `enumFiles()` returns Enumeration of files. The list of files can be thousands or millions. I am using the `hasMoreElements()` and `nextElement()` to read the first 50 files.

What I want is to be able to let say return the next 100 files whenever `myFunction()` is called. Each 100 files will start where it ended previously until there are no more elements in **myFiles**.

I have searched but did not find an answer. I need a little direction on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an iterator of your own.

```
class LimitedIterator<T> implements Iterator<List<T>> {
     private int chunkSize;
     private Iterator<T> baseIterator;
     public LimitedIterator(Iterator<T> base, int size) {
         baseIterator = base;
         chunkSize = size;
     }
     public boolean hasNext() {
         return baseIterator.hasNext();
     }
     public List<T> next() {
         List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(chunkSize);
         for (int i = 0; i < chunkSize && baseIterator.hasNext(); i++) {
             result.add(baseIterator.next();
         }
         return result;
     }
}
```